# Can someone explain this question about random variables?

Tags: probability, random-variables

In each of the following questions, a random variable is described. Identify the random variable as either binomial, Poisson, geometric, negative binomial or hypergeometric and describe a reasonable numerical value for all its parameters.

Two dice are rolled over and over again until a sum of 12 occurs. Let X be the number of trials required. What type of random variable is X and what are its parameters? What is E[X]?

Here is my thinking:

x is a geometric random variable with parameter p=1/36

E[X] = 1/p

= 1/(1/36)

E[X] = 36

Am I going far enough?

Comment: Good, all done.

Comment: Yes, good work.

Comment: Ok great, I just wanted to make sure. Thank you